# что нужно знать в комплекте с react для junior/ middle

Tags: reactjs

в основном когда что то изучаеш и наконец увидел финиш(на данный момент) и проходишь замечаеш что в далеке еще один финиш(например redux,mobX) и так до куда вот и заранее хочется знать на данный момент что нужно знать чтобы писать сайты на react(front end часть(может там еше и backend ест :) ))

Comment: есть backend, а потом все что угодно по желанию: статическая типизация, многопоточность, базы данных, кластера -- развлечения не кончаются)

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov дааа мне уже страшно этот же вопрос для senior задать)))))))))

Comment: Ну junior-senior, это вообще расплывчатые понятия, как и комплекты. У меня вот фулстэк "комплект", но уровень css, например, очень примитивен. Я просто говорю, что всегда есть место для развития.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov ну да ты прав на счет развития там без конца но насчет позиций конечно в гугл джун это сениор в какой то левой компании но у них должны быть границы если брать какую то конкретную группу кампаний